# How to store an Object into a SQLite database in Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I need some help to store a Object in an SQLite database using Android.I don't know whether it is possible or not.If it is possible means please give some code snippets to create a table which can store an object.

Regards,
Rajapandian.K

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to store a Java object, try with [serialization](http://www.j2ee.me/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/) and [BLOB storing](http://effbot.org/zone/sqlite-blob.htm) instead of creating an [OR Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). Certainly storing serialized objects is not recommendable. There are a lot of well known cases where is a headache to work with those kind of designed databases.