# Can I save a string array to strings.xml at runtime?

Tags: java, android

This is my array 
`String colors[] = {"Red","Blue","White","Yellow","Black", "Green","Purple","Orange","Grey"};` 
i want to put this array's values to `<strings-array > </string-array>` in values/string.xml at runtime. is it possible ?? if possible then how ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

And get them like this

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```

Comment: i want to reverse structure of your answer

Comment: No. strings.xml cannot be changed in the Runtime. But you can use SharedPreferences to save your strings there.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813841/storing-a-string-array-in-the-sharedpreferences